# How to test to see if mySql Database is working?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio-2010

I am new to MySQL database, I am using Visual Studio C# to connect to my database. I have got a following select method. How can I run it to check if it is working?

**EDITED The open and close connection methods**

```
//Open connection to database
    private bool OpenConnection()
    {
        try
        {
           // connection.open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            //When handling errors, your application's response based 
            //on the error number.
            //The two most common error numbers when connecting are as follows:
            //0: Cannot connect to server.
            //1045: Invalid user name and/or password.
            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 0:
                   MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.");
                    break;

                case 1045:
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Close connection
    private bool CloseConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Select method which is in the same class as the close and open connection as shown above

```
 public List<string>[] Select()
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Questions";

        //Create a list to store the result
        List<string>[] list = new List<string>[3];
        list[0] = new List<string>();
        list[1] = new List<string>();
        list[2] = new List<string>();
        list[3] = new List<string>();
        list[4] = new List<string>();
        list[5] = new List<string>();
        list[6] = new List<string>();
        list[7] = new List<string>();

        //Open connection
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            //Create Command
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            //Create a data reader and Execute the command
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            //Read the data and store them in the list
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                list[0].Add(dataReader["id"] + "");
                list[1].Add(dataReader["difficulty"] + "");
                list[2].Add(dataReader["qustions"] + "");
                list[3].Add(dataReader["c_answer"] + "");
                list[4].Add(dataReader["choiceA"] + "");
                list[5].Add(dataReader["choiceB"] + "");
                list[6].Add(dataReader["choiceC"] + "");
                list[7].Add(dataReader["choiceD"] + "");
            }

            //close Data Reader
            dataReader.Close();

            //close Connection
            this.CloseConnection();

            //return list to be displayed
            return list;
        }
        else
        {
            return list;
        }
    }
```

This method is in a separate class which has got all the database connection settings. Now that I want to call this method from my main class to test it to see if it's working, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an object instance of that DB class and then call the Select() method.
So, supposing that this DB class is named `QuestionsDB` you should write something like this:

```
QuestionDB questionDAL = new QuestionDB();
List<string>[] questions = questionDAL.Select();
```

However, before this, please correct this line

```
List<string>[] list = new List<string>[8];  // you need 8 lists for your db query
```

You could check if you have any record testing if the first list in your array list has more than zero elements.

```
if(questions[0].Count > 0)
  ... // you have read records.
```

However, said that, I will change your code adding a specific class for questions and using a list(of Question) instead of an array of list
So, for example, create a class like this

```
public class Question
{
    public string ID;
    public string Difficulty;
    public string Question;
    public string RightAnswer;
    public string AnswerA;
    public string AnswerB;
    public string AnswerC;
    public string AnswerD;
}
```

and change your select to return a List(of Question)

```
 List<Question> list = new List<Question>;
 ......
 while (dataReader.Read())
 {
      Question qst = new Question();
      qst.ID = dataReader["id"] + "";
      qst.Difficulty = dataReader["difficulty"] + "";
      qst.Question = dataReader["qustions"] + "";
      qst.RightAnswer = dataReader["c_answer"] + "";
      qst.AnswerA = dataReader["choiceA"] + "";
      qst.AnswerB = dataReader["choiceB"] + "";
      qst.AnswerC = dataReader["choiceC"] + "";
      qst.AnswerD = dataReader["choiceD"] + "";
      list.Add(qst);
 }
 return list;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. I made a button to help me with this testing. When the button is pressed, it will run the select method. But I am having an error at MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); Saying the connection must be valid and open

Comment: Then the code from `this.OpenConnection` is not working as expected. Probably you should show the code for that method to understand what's going on.

Comment: please have a look above for the edited version of my code which now includes the openConnection.

Comment: You edit shows that the connection.Open method is commented out, so the connection is closed when you try to run the Select method and thus you get the exception.

Comment: oops, didn't see that :D. But now it's giving me the "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow" error on connection.Open(). Such a pain in the ass. I got this code by following one of the tutorial for connecting to a database.

Comment: I can't explain that. Could you give the connection string used?

Comment: string connectionString;
            connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
                    database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

Comment: Thanks for the accept, but could you tell me how do you have resolved your arithmetic overflow? Just curious.

Comment: It didn't. I couldn't figure it ut

Answer (score 0):

You can test whether the method works by writing a unit test for it. A good unit testing frame work is [Nunit](http://www.nunit.org/). Before you call this you must create and open a connection to the DB:

```
    //Open connection
    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
```

as the other person said, you will want to fix the lists up.

Comment: I have done so, I have this method in my DBConn class. But even then when I call the select method from a different class it's saying the connection must be valid and open. Any idea where I am going wrong?